# Dojo xhrget response

Tags: ajax, json, dojo

I make a xhrget request to my servlet in dojo. Response is a json object or json array.

But when print the response it gives as Object[] object. How to get the json objects as it was send?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "print" the response? If you convert an object to a string (via document.write, for instance) then it renders as the strange `[object Object]`.

You can use console.log instead of printing it to the debugging console, do this

```
press F12 on Chrome / IE to make that appear
```

Comment: No I just put an alert to see whether i receive the content correctly. I need to update the content of the data store by the response. How to do it?

Comment: @john: alert converts things to a string as I mentioned. You already have the array/object you need and the only problem is how you printed it.

Answer (score 0):

you may need specify "handleAs" attribute with "json" in ioArgs to parse the response text as Json object:

```
var xhrArgs = {
        url: "/foo/bar.json", // uri to your remote json resource
        handleAs: "json",
        load: function(data, ioargs) {
            // data is the parsed JavaScript object you want 
        },
        error: function(error, ioargs) {

        }
    }

//Call the asynchronous xhrGet
var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
```

Or you get respond string only that contains json representation. then parse it with dojo.toJson in your load callback function:

```
var obj = dojo.toJson(data);
```